# Can't download packages spyder anaconda geopandas

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, geopandas

I have some problems using the package geopandas and now I ran into three problems! First it did not seem to work and I found online that it is possible because I used pip & conda. Trying to fix the problem I deleted Spyder and Anaconda but now I can't download packages anymore.

The first problem is that I can't find my downloaded packages in Spyder, I think this is because I downloaded Spyder on Windows, probably with a stand alone version. In this article https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=run%20cell I found that I need to run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels
```

Then here starts my second problem. When I try to run this I get this error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

I don't know how to solve this.

And then, of course, I still would like to use the geopandas package but hopefully I can solve this now since I found some youtube videos.

Can someone help?

Kind Regards,

Tessa

I uninstalled Anaconda.

This are the versions I have at the moment:
Spyder - Spyder IDE 5.4.0 (standalone)
Anaconda Navigator 2.3.1 (it can upgrade to Navigator 2.3.2) but this takes forever!

Comment: Update* 

With the pip packagemanager I used the command: pip install spyder-kernels and reset the kernel of spyder. So now, I can see the packages again. However, I probably need conda to install the geopandas package and don't understand why I keep ketting the solving environment errors as displayed above!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please run in a terminal `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge geopandas spyder-kernels`. Then follow the instructions in [our documentation](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to connect the standalone Spyder to that environment. That should solve your problem.

Comment: adding to this - you can create a ton of headache by mixing and matching conda channels. Anaconda is a specific version of conda that comes bundled with a ton of packages from the `defaults` channel. if you then try to install things from `conda-forge` (which is good), they'll conflict with defaults and blow up on you like this. instead, I'd recommend [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) or its faster cousin [`mambaforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge), which set `conda-forge` as the default